# Add a certain character to a string (For each combination possible) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

For example, I want that if I have a string `helloWorld` and a character `#`

The program would spit these:

`h#elloworld , he#lloworld , ...` and so on, but then it jump to two #'s:

`h#e#lloworld , h#el#loworld, ...` and then it jumps to three #'s and so on..

But two or more consecutive #'s is not allowed, and no # before and after the string. Only in the middle.

These are not allowed: `#he#llo#wor#ld` because it has a # before the actual string.
`he##llowor#ld` because it has 2 consecutive # and also `he#llo#wor#ld#` is not allowed as it has a hashtag after the actual string..

This made me think a lot and I did not quite understood how to come up with a program, I tried this:

```
def eachOptChar(str, c):
    from math import comb

    listOfOpts = []
    l = len(str)

    for i in range(1, l-1):
        for j in range(1, l - 1):
            combL = comb(i, j)
            for _ in range(combL):
                listOfOpts.append(str[:i] + c + str[i + 1:])
                j+=1
    return listOfOpts
```

My thinking: I tried to use combinatorics, first I choose how many chars to put, and add it to the string and append to the list. But it came up with only the solution of one #'s (and a lot of times...)

Is there an elegant way of doing it? Thank you!

I would appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Update #2:* This short script generates all possible permutations that satisfy the stated constraints.

To help understand now the script works, print the value of the "binary" variable and see how it relates to the "line" variable. Also note that "i" is always even in order to prevent adding a "." at the end of the line. (I'm nearly blind so I used a dot which I find easier to distinguish from the pound sign.)

Enjoy!

```
def foo(str, c):
    length = len(str)
    for n in range(0, 2**length, 2):
        binary = f'{n:{length}b}'
        line = ''
        for i in range(length):
            line += str[i]
            if binary[i] == '1':
                line += c
        print(line)

foo('Hello', '.')
```

*Output*

```
Hello
Hell.o
Hel.lo
Hel.l.o
He.llo
He.ll.o
He.l.lo
He.l.l.o
H.ello
H.ell.o
H.el.lo
H.el.l.o
H.e.llo
H.e.ll.o
H.e.l.lo
H.e.l.l.o
```

---

Update: copy.copy() removed as it is not needed.

This code will do what you seem to be describing but it does NOT generate all possible combinations of "#" characters within the given string!

Script:

```
def insert_char(c, string, index):
    return string[:index] + c + string[index:]

def do(str, c, n):
    l = len(str)
    for i in range(n, l):
        new = insert_char(c, str, i)
        print(new)
        if i == n:
            first = new
    return first

str = 'Hello World'
l = len(str)
for i in range(1, 2*l-1, 2):
    str = do(str, '.', i)
```

Output:

```
H.ello World
He.llo World
Hel.lo World
Hell.o World
Hello. World
Hello .World
Hello W.orld
Hello Wo.rld
Hello Wor.ld
Hello Worl.d
H.e.llo World
H.el.lo World
H.ell.o World
H.ello. World
H.ello .World
H.ello W.orld
H.ello Wo.rld
H.ello Wor.ld
H.ello Worl.d
H.e.l.l.o. World
H.e.l.l.o .World
H.e.l.l.o W.orld

...

H.e.l.l.o. .W.o.rld
H.e.l.l.o. .W.or.ld
H.e.l.l.o. .W.orl.d
H.e.l.l.o. .W.o.r.ld
H.e.l.l.o. .W.o.rl.d
H.e.l.l.o. .W.o.r.l.d
```